# Insert node after node in abstract syntax tree - Eclipse CDT

Tags: java, c, eclipse-cdt, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to insert node after another comment

```
/**************/
/* Prototypes */
/**************/
--->want to declare function prototype here
int x = 5;
```

So I get the comment node in the ast via this code

```
@Override
protected int visit(IASTComment comment) {
    if(comment.getRawSignature().contains("Prototypes")) {
        prototypeNode = comment;
    }
    return super.visit(comment);
}
```

then I want to insert this node below after the comment

```
INodeFactory factory = ast.getASTNodeFactory();
IASTSimpleDeclaration simpleDeclaration = factory.newSimpleDeclaration(functionDef.getDeclSpecifier());
simpleDeclaration.addDeclarator(functionDef.getDeclarator());

ASTRewrite rewriter = ASTRewrite.create(ast);
//I want to insert the simpleDeclaration node after the comment node  
**enter code here**


Change c = rewriter.rewriteAST();
try {
    c.perform(new NullProgressMonitor());
} catch (CoreException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ASTRewrite` has an `insertBefore(IASTNode parent, IASTNode insertionPoint, IASTNode newNode, TextEditGroup editGroup)` method that you can use for this purpose.

In your case, you'd want to call it with:

- Your `simpleDeclaration` as the argument for `newNode`
- The declaration for `int x = 5;` (which you would find during traversal) as the argument for `insertionPoint`
- The parent of the `insertionPoint` (which may be the `IASTTranslationUnit`) as the argument for `parent`
- You can pass `null` for the `editGroup` argument. (Based on existing uses of ASTRewrite in the CDT codebase, it seems like the purpose of this optional argument is to associate a set of edits with a description/label that can later be shown in e.g. a refactoring UI.)

Comment: I know ast write before method, and I don't know the actual code may be could be int x = 5 or anything else, x = 5 is just an example. I need more generic way, I know the comment and it is static and fixed to like this /**************/
/* Prototypes */
/**************/

Comment: @MostafaHassan: If you know the `IASTComment` node, you can iterate over the global declarations (children of `IASTTranslationUnit`) and find the first one whose starting offset (`IASTNode.getFileLocation().getNodeOffset()`) is past the comment node.